# How do I make a Multidimensional Array for large data storage in Obj-c?

Tags: objective-c, multidimensional-array

I am fairly new at object oriented programming (but am starting to pick up fairly quickly), and am working on an application for the iphone. I need to make a multidimensional array, (10,000 or more rows, 8 columns) ordered as such:3 columns should contain boolean values, one should contain an integer, two need to hold GPS coordinates (usually have a decimal, like 62.422342), one needs to hold a 30 character string. is there an easy way to create such an array, and if so, to define the array elements prior to user interation?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to make each row an object, and keep an NSArray of those objects. Each "column" would be a property on the object. This would be a good choice if each row actually does represent an object.

Otherwise you could have an NSArray of NSArrays to represent the 2D array. Not a perfect solution, because it's possible to have rows/columns of different lengths, but it would do.

You could always roll your own, and make a kind of "Table" class that acts as a 2D NSArray and enforces correct row/column length.

Answer (score 0):

You should maybe have a look at Core Data and store your data in a database. I'm currently reading [Beginning iPhone 3 Development](http://www.apress.com/book/view/9781430224594) and it's got a chapter about Core Data. It doesn't go into very much detail, but is a good introduction and should be enough to get started.

Comment: are there any online resources for Core Data? I have a book on programming with Cocoa, perhaps that can assist as well?

Comment: Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X (http://www.bignerdranch.com/products.shtml) covers some Core Data and there are a few tutorials out there, for instance http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000085.php. There's also some stuff directly from Apple: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html or http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html and probably more Have a look on Google.

Comment: Another thing I wanted to mention: Core Data is only available in iPhone OS 3 and up, so if you need to support older versions you can't use Core Data.

Comment: Thanks, there were some helpful hints in your links and im finally starting to create my database, albeit slowly..